# Why does assignment to mongo document field sometimes not go into the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a mongo database with a few thousand 'Ticket' documents that I'm accessing via the rails console.
For some, but not all, of these documents, when I perform the following commands from the console, I get unexpected results: the value of a field is not updated.
Rails 1.9.3-p194, mongo 2.0.4

```
Ticket.where("title" => /failing example/).first.status
=> "Assigned"
Ticket.where("title" => /failing example/).first.status='Completed' 
=> "Completed" 
Ticket.where("title" => /failing example/).first.status
"Assigned"
```

Huh?  OK, let's try it another way.

```
Ticket.where("title" => /failing example/).first do |t|
    t.status='Completed'
    t.save
 end
 "Completed"
 Ticket.where("title" => /failing example/).first.status
 "Assigned"
```

This has me confused.

Comment: I'd suggest you go to the monogodb console and check if there are multiple documents that match the criteria specified as that could explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead so that you know you're using the same ticket:

```
@ticket = Ticket.where("title" => /failing example/).first
@ticket.status
=> "Assigned"
@ticket.status = 'Completed'
=> "Completed"
@ticket.status
=> ...
```

Ok, from your attempted edit to my answer it seems like the objects aren't passing validations and being saved correctly. Double check the validations in the `Ticket` model and make sure that all required columns are present.

Comment: Thank you, Mind.blank.  That indeed was the problem.